# Repeat users input using PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I am looking to make a program that listens to what the user inputs and than it will repeat the same thing. Repeating should be easy, but what I find hard to do is to store the user input inside a list so than I can do the same thing one by one. One of the other things I don't know how to do is the timing, I also want the timing to be the same as the user input, The way I think this can be done is using another list just for the timings but im not sure thats a good idea or not, can anyone help me?

Comment: What have you already tried to do on your own?

Comment: not really anything that worked probably, thats why i posted the question, PySimpleGUI really confused me after a while.

Comment: Try to help, but don't know what the question is.

Comment: Provide the basic GUI Interface and sample code. 
If not sure watch some tutorials or see 
1. Cookbook: https://www.pysimplegui.org/en/latest/cookbook/
2. Demo Programs: https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/tree/master/DemoPrograms